# Bin executables can't be found after changing `modules-dir`

Tags: pnpm

I have a need to use some folder name other than `node_modules` for the dependencies of my packages in a pnpm workspace. I thought this seemed like it would probably be plagued with systemic issues, but I was excited to see the [`modules-dir` option](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#modules-dir) for the npmrc file which might magically fix my problems. Unfortunately, after editing it, now all of my scripts that execute tools from npm dependency packages fail because they can't find those tools.

I tried several things like manually pointing the script to the new folder's `.bin` subfolder or adding that folder to the `PATH` variable before executing the command, but they all yielded other problems that don't seem like they're taking me in the right direction. I also tried switching to have [`node-linker`](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#node-linker) set to `pnp` instead, but I understand that even less since it's still putting things in the `node_modules` folder (which seems contrary to the "no node_modules" description of that mode).

Am I missing something that's necessary to make this work? Is this something that can even be done, or would it require too much rewiring? If not, why do the `modules-dir` and pnp options even exist?

*Context on why I want this*: I have multiple systems building code from the same shared volume, and they have different operating systems, so some dependencies install very differently (this whole setup may seem like a very bad idea, but I assure you it's otherwise quite safe and stable in this case). I'd like both systems to be able to play together nicely by having pnpm use a system-specific alternative to the `node_modules` folder. I'm also open to other ideas on how to accomplish this sort of harmony if there's another strategy I'm not seeing.

*Edit: The app I'm testing this with is a vite web app, if that matters. I also tried running the app with `pnpm dlx vite --mode development` when using PnP mode, but it still complains about not being able to find the file `.../tmp/dlx-95108/node_modules/vite/package.json`.*